# what data type should be used for storing a fixed monthly fee amount in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have an application where subscribers will pay a monthly fee depending on their plan. While researching what the best data type to store currency, I found out that many are suggesting `numeric` over `money` for precision and accuracy but I'm not sure if that applies to my case.

In my case there is a fixed set of plans and each costs a fixed amount of money. something like plan A will cost `9.99`/month and plan B `4.99`/month.

I wonder if the `numeric` type in my situation will have any advantages over the `money` type?  or do I even need these two data types at all in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I wonder if the numeric type in my situation will have any advantages over the money type?*

It's the other way round: the money type does not offer any advantages at all.

`numeric` is definitely the better choice.

See also [don't use the money type](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) in the Postgres Wiki